# how to access a server in a VPN from a home computer via a separate notebook with the vpn connection

Tags: linux, vpn, remote, ssh-tunneling

For my local work environment I would like to access all my companies server directly from my workstation elsewhere.
To make this really fun the only access possible is via the VPN on the company managed notebook and the notebook does not allow connections to the local network.

Obviously, no IT department is helping you with such a problem.

Comment: why don't you ask the IT department for help?

Answer (score 0):

If you can SSH to the company notebook from your home computer then you can use [SSH Tunnelling](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/SSH_tunneling) or [SSH Jump Hosts](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/SSH_jump_host)

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of ssh tunnneling documentation, but they dont cover this specific scenario.

So to get from 
     Workstation <-> Notebook <-> Company Network
we need an extra system on N which plays the router to connect the separate networks.

We need an additional VM on the Notebook with 2 network ports. 
One is connected to the host network via NAT, 
the other connected to the LAN via a bridged connection.

So we can get a connection as
 W <-> VM1 <-> VM2 <-> N1 <-> N2 <-> CN

This can be configured via ssh config.
An example with some bogus IPs.

```
W =   192.0.0.3   <LAN>      VM1 = 192.0.0.2
VM1 = 192.0.0.2   <route>    VM2 = 10.0.0.3
VM2 = 10.0.0.3    <NAT>      NATRouter = 10.0.0.1
NR =  10.0.0.1    <nat2host> N1 = 20.0.0.4
N2 = 20.0.0.4     <vpnroute> CN 0.0.0.0/0
```

This is the description of the network hops between the system. 
So to connect to a server in the CN we need to solve 2 separate steps.
We need to setup ssh configurations for the intermediate hops.
.ssh/config entries:

```
# reaching the VM
Host VM
    User            vmuser
    IdentityFile    ~/.ssh/vm_id_rsa
    ForwardX11      yes

# reaching a host inside the CN
Host CNhost
    User            companyuser
    IdentityFile    ~/.ssh/cnhost_id_rsa
    ForwardX11      yes
    ProxyCommand    ssh -A vm nc %h %p 2>  /dev/null
```

Another important issue is the correct routing within the VM.
The route to the bridged LAN 192.0.0.0/24 needs to have a lower metric than the default route to the NAT 10.0.0.1.

```
vm$ ip route
default via 10.0.0.1 metric 100
10.0.0.0/24 dev nat1 metric 100
192.0.0.0/24 dev bridge1 metric 99
```

---

Now the interesting case is when we want to also access a server on an internal network which is accessible only from a server already inside the company network.
A classical jumphost configuration.
For that we need another .ssh/config entry

```
# reaching a host on a CN internal network
Host CNInternalhost
    User            cnInternalUser
    IdentityFile    ~/.ssh/cninternalhost_id_rsa
    ForwardX11      yes
    ProxyCommand    ssh -A CNhost nc %h %p 2>  /dev/null
```

---

**Now we should be able to simply ssh into the CNInternalhost.** 

If not the routeing tables need to be checked. (e.g. missing routes or wrong metrics)

---

**But we also want to access a service on this internalhost directly from our local workstation!**

For this we  now create the tunnel using the hops preconfigured in the .ssh/config

```
ssh -L <portOnLocalhost>:CNInternalhost:<portOnCNInternalHost> CNhost
```

*Now we can access CNInternalhost: < portOnCNInternalHost > on localhost:< portOnLocalhost >*

If we want to reuse an additional network name (ServerX) in our local setup, we can add a host alias on our local host for our LAN ip and create an additional tunnel for it.

```
echo 192.0.0.3 ServerX >> /etc/hosts
```

This also requires an additonal .ssh/config entry:

```
# configuring another host on the CN internal network
Host serverX
    User            cnInternalUser
    IdentityFile    ~/.ssh/serverX_id_rsa
    ForwardX11      yes
    ProxyCommand    ssh -A CNhost nc %h %p 2>  /dev/null
```

with this ssh config we can now create a  tunnel like this

```
ssh -L serverX:<portOnLocalhost>:serverX:<portOnLocalhost> CNhost
```

as long as serverX is accessible from CNhost.
And we can do a:

```
$ wget serverX:<portOnLocalhost>
```